# Program stuck after opening a popup

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, popup, automated-tests

The tool clicks a button and a modal window appears (where I need to fill in some information and later move to parent window). But as soon as the new modal window appears, my code stops. The code resumes once I **manually close the new popup window.**

Since the code itself halts, I am not able to perform any actions in the new popup window, nor in the parent window.

```
System.out.println ("Up");
WebElement addButton = driver.findElement(By.id("btnAdd"));
addButton.click ();
System.out.println ("Down");
```

In the above code, **Up** gets printed in the console while **Down** doesn't get printed until I manually close the popup window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally a solution after wasting a lot of days.

The **only way** is to *not use showModalDialog*. This can be done by adding the folowing before the .click() :

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.showModalDialog = window.open;");
```

which will call window.open instead of window.showModalDialog.

Answer (score 2):

```
 driver.switchTo().alert();
```

write this line of code after clicking on button control will get switch to the pop up and then write

```
alert.accept();
```

alert will get close

Answer (score 1):

you need to move control to your pop-up window first before doing any operation on pop-up window:-

code to move selenium control on pop-up window:-

```
 driver.switchTo().alert();
```

Now you can perform you action on pop-up.

To send your control back on main window use below code:-

```
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: But right after opening the pop up, my project halts. Even if I write driver.swithTo.alert() after addButton.click (), it doesn't get evoked.

Comment: if there is only 2 button present than you can use  driver.switchTo().alert().accept(); or  driver.switchTo().alert().dismiss();

Comment: also please change the browser and look if it helps

Comment: The problem is, **once a modal window has evoked, the code stops**. So I loose control for both parent and child (modal window).**

Comment: do you have put some wait there ... try that too

Comment: wait before opening the modal window ?