# Selenium : window does not open after click

Tags: python, selenium

I am using selenium 3.4.3 and python 3.6.2 and I have a problem when I want to open a new window.
First of all here is the part of the code where it fails :

```
def wait_and_find_by_id(element_id):
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, element_id))
    )
    return driver.find_element_by_id(element_id)

VA = wait_and_find_by_id('VA_id')
driver.execute_script("window.showModalDialog = window.open;")
VA.click()

# Wait for the new window to open
time.sleep(2)
driver.switch_to_window(driver.window_handles[2])

tarifaire = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='tarif_id']/span/span")
driver.execute_script("window.showModalDialog = window.open;")
tarifaire.click()
```

I have no problem with the first window opening (`VA.click()`) but when I try to open the second window (`tarifaire.click()`), the window seems to refresh and nothing else happens.

I tried to run the script without the second instance of `driver.execute_script`, and the window opens but as a popup, and my program is stuck as long as I don't close the popup.

I can give you more information if you need it to help me.

Update : Turns out it works well with ChromeDriver, I don't even have to use `driver.execute_script`. But still, if someone knows why the above script does not works with Firefox's Geckodriver, I'd be glad to hear it !

Comment: You should give the URL.

Comment: Sorry I can't give you the URL, it's a Web app still private for the moment

Comment: so it will be hard to help you. why are you playing with two windows and not just one? + what driver is used?

Comment: I am using Firefox's geckodriver. When I click to open the new page, it automatically opens it in a new window. Originally it is a popup but with the `driver.execute_script` it allows me to open it as a new window.

Comment: well, can't say it would works, but I struggle a lot to handle two windows with firefox but it worked like a charm with chrome ..

Comment: Ok, I'll try that and tell you if it works !

Comment: well, to answer this quetion we need to understand why are you opening new window using such an unusual way `window.showModalDialog = window.open;`? imo you are loading modal dialog twice, so behavior is as expected.

Comment: The reason why I am using`window.showModalDialog = window.open;` is because the new page normally opens as a popup that stops my program. This line allows me to open it as a new window and do other actions on it. You can find more info on that suject at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36324436/program-stuck-after-opening-a-pop-up-using-selenium-webdriver

Comment: Thanks Arount. It works really well with chromedriver.